# How to get index of multiple maximum value in List

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

In given list of Integers i want to find the multiple index of maximum value in List.

For example,

```
List<Integer> len=Arrays.asList(9,3,6,5,4,9);
```

Now i want to find the largest element which is 9 and its all index which are 0 and 5.

i have tried following code but it only gives me the first occurrence of element so from this code i am getting output only 0 not 5.

```
IntStream.range(0,len.size()).reduce((a, b) -> len.get(a) < len.get(b)?b:a).ifPresent(ix -> System.out.println("Index -"+ix));
```

So how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int max = len.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, len.size()).filter(ix -> len.get(ix).intValue() == max).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Of course you have to handle the case when max is not present

Comment: but that would stream twice... interesting if it can be done with a single stream.

Comment: `.intValue()` is unnecessary. Java will auto-unbox.

Comment: Changing first line to `int max = len.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().orElse(0);` would resolve issue raised by @grozandrei.

Comment: Besides that, using `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `Integer::compareTo` might be preferable…

Comment: can use   int max = Collections.max(len); function to get Max value

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use only one `Stream` pipeline:

```
List<Integer> len = Arrays.asList(9, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9);

List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, len.size()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(len::get, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()),
        m -> m.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : m.lastEntry().getValue()));
System.out.println(indices);
```

First group your indices to the respective values in your list. Then you have to decide what to do if the intermediate map is empty. Either you throw an `NoSuchElementException` or return an empty list. In my example I chose the latter case.

---

Result:

> [0, 5]

Comment: pretty nice :) one plus

Answer (score 1):

If the result doesn't have to be a `Stream` or `Optional` you could accomplish the task using this code:

```
IntStream.range(0, len.size()).boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> len.get(i)).reversed())
    .reduce(-1, (ixMax, ix) -> {
        if (ixMax == -1 || len.get(ixMax) == len.get(ix)) {
            System.out.println("Index -" + ix);
            return ix;
        } else {
            return ixMax;
        }
    });
```

Although answering the question it's probably neither concise nor very performant to be honest. With some work it should be possible to replace the if-else block with code making use of `Optional`.